# Pycharm: Getting "ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='...', port=443): Max retries exceeded", even though not behind a proxy

Tags: python, macos, proxy, pycharm

I'm working on a work PC (Macbook - OS sierra 10.16) from **home**.
While at **work**, we do use proxy so I use MacOS "network locations" feature (System Preferences -> Networks -> Location) to have proxy only for work networks, and while at **home** I use a different "location" without any proxy configurations (I've double and triple checked).

Except that I've made sure that i don't have any proxy env variables set (like `http_proxy` or `https_proxy`).

`scutil --proxy` result show no proxy is set:

```
<dictionary> {
  ExceptionsList : <array> {
    0 : *.local
    1 : 169.254/16
  }
  FTPPassive : 1
}
```

I am able to access the network from any application without any problem from **home**, the only problem is when I'm trying to run a python script from `Pycharm` that access the network (**no** proxy configured in Pycharm -> Preferences -> HTTP Proxy).

**I'm able to run the same script from terminal.**

And last, if I turn VPN on, I'm able to run the script from Pycharm without any problems (Meaning Proxy is set :())

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I've manage to figure out the source of the problem.
It seems that `Pycharm` is loading `~/.bash_profile` when it starts.

**Removing my proxy exports from `~/.bash_profile` and restarting Pycharm resolved the issue for me.**